# onclick set to undefined but I have correct syntax, no typos?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

I keep getting the above error and I cannot figure out where or how it is going wrong. The error is instant whenever the page loads, I don't have to click any buttons for the error. I believe I have the correct syntax and as far as my own eyes can tell, no typos.

Below are the relevant HTML and JS code. I like to code in small parts to make sure every small part works before moving onto the next.

**HTML**

```
    <h4>Enter Hex Code</h4>
    <input id="hexInput"></input></br>
    <button>Generate</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var hexInput = document.getElementById("hexInput");
    var generateButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

    var generateHex = function() {
     console.log(hexInput);
    };

    generateButton.onclick = generateHex;
```

Apologies if I formatted the code incorrectly on the post. Newly registered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your script earlier in the page than the HTML it uses, like the snippet below? If so, then the `var hexInput...` line is running before the browser has created the DOM elements.

```
<script>
var hexInput = document.getElementById("hexInput");
var generateButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

var generateHex = function() {
 console.log(hexInput);
};

generateButton.onclick = generateHex;
</script>

<h4>Enter Hex Code</h4>
<input id="hexInput" />
<button>Generate</button>
```

You can reverse the order of the blocks and things will be fine (as in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeqt513r/)). Alternately, if the script is in a separate file that is loaded with `<script src="...`", the entire page will be loaded before the script runs.

Comment: I...cannot believe I did not think of this. I was too focused on the syntax I forgot to check the logistics of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Your trimming it down to just the two snippets made it easy as that (or some variant) was all it could be. (Or, if it had been something else, I would have been totally lost. :))